# First isomorphism theorem visualisation on cyclic groups such as $C_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, visualization, group-homomorphism

I want to demonstrate the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem) on cyclic groups such as $C_4$. I find it hard to see how this map works.

[image]

$C_4$ has the cycle $(13)(24)$. The cycle is a composition function so that

$$(f\circ g)(1)=3,$$
$$(f\circ g)(2)=4,$$ 
$$(f\circ g)(3)=1,$$ and 
$$(f\circ g)(4)=2.$$

The isomorphism visualisation with arrows may be better explained in terms of other cyclic [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group#Motivation_for_the_name_.22quotient.22) (eg [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmpWp.png) and [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ077.png)). I find it hard to understand the isomorphism theorem, ([trivia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlPwy.png)). Perhaps the demostrations on cyclic groups could help to understand the first isomorphism theorem so:

**How can you visualise the first isomorphism theorem on cyclic groups?**

Comment: What do you want to visualise? Does the diagram you posted count as a visualisation?

Comment: @neptun I cannot yet understand the first isomorphism theorem: how is it related to the cyclic groups? How can you construct the homomorphism? What are the zeros? What is the K? What is $f, l, \pi$ for cyclic groups such as $C_4$? I feel the visualisation could help to understand the theorem.

Comment: $f$ is a group homomorphism to another group. $\pi$ is the projection on the quotient group, taking elements to their equivalence classes modulo the kernel. You have specified the group $G$ but no $f$ or $H$, making further explanations quite hard

Comment: one might remark that the isomorphism of the theorem is the one between $G/\text{ker}\ f$ and $\text{im}\ f$ which the diagram you posted does not really illuminate

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need another group *besides* $C_4$. Let's choose $C_2$, and what we'll do is send:

$(1\ 2\ 3\ 4) \mapsto (1\ 3)(2\ 4)\\
(1\ 3)(2\ 4) \mapsto e\\
(1\ 4\ 3\ 2) \mapsto (1\ 3)(2\ 4)\\
e \mapsto e$

Alternately, we could send the generator $x$ of $C_4$ to the generator $y$ of $C_2$, effectively sending:

$x^{k \text{ mod }4} \mapsto y^{k \text{ mod }2}$ (this may be easier to verify as a homomorphism).

We can "get rid" of the $x$ and $y$ by considering the *additive* groups:

$\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ and simply sending $[k]_4 \mapsto [k]_2$.

In any case, all of these are "diagrammatically similar", and we find that:

$C_4/\text{ker }f \cong C_2$.

The kernel of $f$ (if we write our two groups as "powers" of their generators $x$ and $y$, respectively) is $\{e,x^2\}$. Let's call this $K$. The elements of $C_4/K$ are:

$K = \{e,x^2\}\\xK = \{x,x^3\}.$

It should be clear that $KK = K$, that $K(xK) = (xK)K = xK$, and that $(xK)^2 = x^2K = K$.

Thus $xK \mapsto f(x) = y$ is an explicit isomorphism the theorem says exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of visualization you're looking for here, but there's really not much to the theorem. Suppose we have an arbitrary group of homomorphism $f:G \to H$. We can make it surjective by restricting $H$ to the image of $H$, and we can make it injective by replacing $G$ by $G/\ker f$ (note that a map $f:G/N \to H$ is the same as a map $f:G \to H$ that vanishes on $N$). The induced map $f:G/\ker f \to \operatorname{im} f$ is then an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you +1. About the injectivity part. Why does $f$ become injective with the restriction on the domain $G/ker(f)$? Does this notation $N$ mean that the kernel is a normal subgroup $N:=ker(f)$? $ker(f)=\{f(\mathbf x)=0 \mid \mathbf x\in k[x_1...x_n]\}$. Why not $ker_1(f)=\{f(\mathbf x)=1 \mid \mathbf x\in k[x_1...x_n]\}$ or let say $ker_{777}(f)=\{f(\mathbf x)=777 \mid \mathbf x\in k[x_1...x_n]\}$? What is the zero in $ker(f)$?